# How to make ubuntu OS to get sleep using python?

Tags: python, operating-system

using python coding i want to make make the system to get sleep state , is that possible ? 
i need the solution in Ubuntu , i can find that for windows but for Ubuntu is their any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using os.system you can call terminal commands.
You can for instance use `systemctl hibernate` to get Ubuntu to sleep.

```
import os
os.system("systemctl hibernate")
```

Note: you might need to run your python file using `sudo`.